# Al momento de ejecutar este comando -> composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf en laravel 5.6 me sale lo siguiente

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian ayudar por favor que debo hacer ante este error

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor como funciona y ademas así obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). También podrías revisar [ask] para futuras preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer el error esta asociado con la extension `gd`; debes abrir tu archivo `php.ini` y quitar la `;` de la siguiente extensión para descomentar

Esta así `;extension=php_gd2.dll` debe quedar así `extension=php_gd2.dll`

Basado en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448499/8451749) del sitio en ingles.